# Max Nested Level SQL Server - Create Calendar type table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I currently have a table which holds rate periods for services. These periods need to be created in the following way based on a provided start date and end date

- If start date is not the start of a week, a record must be inserted
  from the Start date until the end of the week containing the start
  date.
- The next record to be inserted will be the start of the week after the start date up until the end date of the last full date prior to the end date (it can be up until the end date, if the end date is a last day of the week.
- There is also a requirement to add individual records for bank holidays

The table is currently populated using recursive stored procedures,but has been failing recently due to exceeding the max nest level for SP', functions etc.

I want to remove this issue and I have no issues creating the table where there are no bank holidays, but I am having problems dealing with the bank holiday insertion and update of previous rates entered.

For example take the following

- Start Date: 5th Jan 2017
- End Date: 8th April 2017
- Last Day of Week: Sunday
- Bank Holidays: Mar 9th and Apr 6th

The returned records should be

- 5th Jan - 8th Jan (5th is not a Monday)
- 9th Jan - 5th Mar (End week prior to Bank Holiday)
- 6th Mar - 8th Mar (part week due to Bank Holiday)
- 9th Mar - 9th Mar (Bank Holiday)
- 10th Mar - 12th Mar (Part week due to Bank Holiday)
- 13th Mar - 2nd Apr (Full weeks)
- 3rd Apr - 5th Apr (Part week due to Bank Holiday)
- 6th Apr - 6th Apr (Bank Holiday)
- 7th Apr - 8th Apr (End of Period)

I have looked into using recursive CTE's to do this but I am having issues with this.
Any ideas on the best way to implement the above?

Comment: I can't say why recursion would be a problem without seeing your code but you don't need to use a recursive CTE. Instead, use either a numbers table or CTE with CROSS JOIN (Cartesian product). A better option is to create a permanent calendar table (you'll fund may examples with an internet search).  One example that uses these methods is http://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that link and see how I get on.